# How to create a completion handler in Swift which I would call optionally?

Tags: swift, completionhandler

Currently, I have a completion handler:

```
open func Start(completion: (() -> Void)) { ... }
```

but in this case I have to always call the `completion`.
How can I make an optional, so in some method I would use `completion` block but in others I would just skip them and do not add to my method calls?

For example, I want the same as in:

```
self.present(<#T##viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController##UIViewController#>, animated: <#T##Bool#>, completion: <#T##(() -> Void)?##(() -> Void)?##() -> Void#>)
```

I've tried

```
open func Start(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) { ... }
```

adding question mark, but in this case I have to call an optional completion block

```
completion?()
```

and I cannot call simply

```
start()
```

where I do not need in completion block. It requires me to call it

Comment: Your code works just fine. You can simply call `start()`. It works just as you want it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it an Optional Parameter with `nil` value by default:

```
open func Start(completion: (() -> Void)! = nil) {
    guard completion != nil else {
        return
    }
    completion()
}
```

Inside some other method:

```
func foo() {

    Start()

    Start(completion: nil)

    Start(completion: {
        // some code
    })

    Start {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that also. It still asks me to call completion block. That's why I've decided to create a question here =/

Comment: @J.Doe You should be able to simply call start() now, not sure why you are having issues. Which Swift version are you using? Also, check my updated answer.

Comment: the latest, Swift 4.2

Comment: It should work then, unless you have some unrelated issues.

Comment: It just seems wrong to declare a variable as implicitly unwrapped and then to give it an initial value of nil. Just make it a normal optional. Get rid of the `guard`. Change the call to `completion?()` and everything works just fine. But then we are back to the original code in the question - which works just fine.

Comment: @rmaddy Agree with that! Just thought he wanted to call completion() (not completion?()) while still keeping it as an Optional Parameter. In fact, before editing my answer - the code was as you suggested. And agree that the guard statement is not needed in that case, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a default value that is not `nil`, e.g. a block that does nothing

```
open func start(completion: @escaping (() -> Void) = {}) {
}
```

However, I don't see what problem you have with calling `completion?()`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code in the question. This answer (and the other one) appears to be unnecessary.